# Signal attached to 3rd party library model not being triggered

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-signals, django-mptt

I've have got a usecase in which I have a model named **"Content"** which inherits from a **3rd party library** I've installed as a pip package known as **"django-mptt"** as shown below.

*content_viewer/models.py*

```
class Content(MPTTModel):
    content_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    content_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    parent = TreeForeignKey(
        "self",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        related_name="children",
    )
```

I'm also using redis cache for cacheops and I've added the configurations as follow in my settings.py.

*dashboard/settings.py*

```
CACHEOPS_REDIS = {
    "host": REDIS_HOST,
    "port": REDIS_PORT,
    "db": 1,
    "socket_timeout": 3,
}

CACHEOPS = {
    "content_viewer.*": {"ops": {"fetch", "get"}, "timeout": 60 * 60},
}
```

***Note:-** **content_viewer** is the name of the **app***

**Requirement:** What I want here is a **post_save signal** on the **MPTTModel** class which should **invalidate/clear** the **redis cache** for the object that has been **created/saved**

I've created a **signal** in my **signals.py** file as below.

*content_viewer/signals.py*

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=MPTTModel)
def clear_redis_cache_for_mptt_instance(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    invalidate_obj(instance)
```

and I've imported the signals inside the **apps.py** file as shown below.

*content_viewer/apps.py*

```
class WorkspaceDisplayConfig(AppConfig):
    name = "content_viewer"

    def ready(self):
        import content_viewer.signals
```

But when I run the code in debug mode the signal seems to be never fired whenever I create an instance of the **Content** object.

can anyone tell me what could I be doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you debugged your app to make sure the `ready` method is being run and that `signals.py` is run too?

Comment: Yes @lain I've debugged the app and the ready method and the signals.py is being run

Comment: And how are you creating/saving the instance? Can you share the code?

Comment: I'm adding the instance from the admin panel

Comment: Just as a test, if you remove `sender=Content` from `@receiver` and you just log/print sender and instance does your function receive signals for other models? What I'm getting at is, does the handler not get registered correctly or does the model genuinely not send the signal

Comment: Yes, my function is receiving signals for other models.

Comment: Can you share your admin that is not triggering the signal?

Comment: @IainShelvington I've updated the real question there was a mistake the signal was supposed to receive the trigger from the MPTTModel class

Comment: @IainShelvington what do you mean by sharing the admin which is not triggering the signal?

Comment: `MPTTModel` is abstract, you can't create instances of it so you'll never get a signal from it. Do you want to receive signals from all subclasses of `MPTTModel` instead?

Comment: Oh I see, so that is the reason I'm not getting any signals for the MPTTModel

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239391/discussion-between-nick-and-iain-shelvington).